# Do the car body types matter in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

Is there any technical difference between the different car body types in Rocket League? Based on my experimentation, there does not seem to be a difference but I could not confirm it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to the developer](https://twitter.com/RocketLeague/status/621181614773571588?lang=en), **the cars have slightly different hitboxes.** Other than that, they have identical stats.

#### Additional Video References

- [What Is The Best Car In Rocket League?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2frkaLE9_Y)
- [Rocket League guide to car differences: Hitbox Comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkyJE8Q3SI0)

Comment: Sounds like you are right. I found this too:

https://twitter.com/RocketLeague/status/621181614773571588?lang=en

Comment: @Hagelt18 Nice find! I tried searching their Twitter for the official response mentioned in the first video, but failed to find it. I'll edit my answer to include it!

Comment: This is the most accurate answer, because it has the hitbox comparison video that Highlights the real difference between the cars, the varied angle of the forward facing hitbox lends a huge strength to the Merc van for most shots, a lower arced shot is more likely to be in goal, but may be easier to block. In higher level gameplay, this advantage is pretty much nullified by skillful opponents, but it is worth note that there is a tactical advantage to the Merc.

Answer (score 4):

Hit box can change *slightly*. Other than that, there is no difference whatsoever.
I'll find an official source if I can, but that's what I've noticed from personal experimentation/gameplay.

Actually, I found a ton of sources (although mostly are unofficial) by simply Googling "rocket league hitboxes". Might be worth a look-through although they just confirm what I say above.
In case you were curious about toppers: they are aesthetic only, performance isn't affected.